# Подсоеденить API twitch.com к Телеграм боту на Python

Tags: python

решил сделать бота, который будет уведомлять пользователей о начале трансляций на платформе Twitch на Python. Не подскажите, как это осуществить и какие для этого API нужны. (Я новичёк в этом деле)

Comment: Самый обычный бот у меня уже есть, нужно подсоеденить к нему теперь API и т. д.

Comment: Что-то вы непосильную для новичка задачу взяли...

Comment: Не ищу легких путей

Comment: Если объём навыков слишком маленький, а задача слишком большая - время на решение будет стремиться к бесконечно большой величине.

Answer (score 1):

Как пример, можете использовать: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI
Получив ключ, создайте обычного бота и создайте обработчик для команды **/start**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    addToBD(message.chat.id)
```

Функция **addToBD** должна принимать один параметер - **id**. Создайте базу данных SQLite3 (db.db допустим) в папке с файлом .ру и сверяйте есть пользователь или его там нет (чтобы не забить БД дублями).

```
def addToDB(id):
    with sqlite3.connect('db.db') as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(f'SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `tgbot` WHERE `user_id` = {id}')

        if cur.fetchone()[0] == 0:
            cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO `tgbot` (`user_id`) VALUES ({id})')
            conn.commit()
```

Пример таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `tgbot` (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `user_id`   INTEGER
);
```

И допустим создадим команду **/alert** которая будет оповещать всех пользователей из БД по ID что начался стрим

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['alert'])
def alert_users(message):
    if message.chat.id == ADMIN_ID:
        sendToAll()
```

**ADMIN_ID** - это ваш Chat ID.
Ну и сама функция sendToAll():

```
def sendToAll():
    with sqlite3.connect('db.db') as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(f'SELECT `user_id` FROM `tgbot`')
        rows = cur.fetchall()

        for row in rows:
            bot.send_message(row[0], 'Stream started!')
```

И на финал, пример кода (я его не тестил, писал в Notepad++):

```
import sqlite3
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")


def sendToAll():
    with sqlite3.connect('db.db') as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(f'SELECT `user_id` FROM `tgbot`')
        rows = cur.fetchall()

        for row in rows:
            bot.send_message(row[0], 'Stream started!')


def addToDB(id):
    with sqlite3.connect('db.db') as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(f'SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `tgbot` WHERE `user_id` = {id}')

        if cur.fetchone()[0] == 0:
            cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO `tgbot` (`user_id`) VALUES ({id})')
            conn.commit()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['alert'])
def alert_users(message):
    if message.chat.id == ADMIN_ID:
        sendToAll()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    addToDB(message.chat.id)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть у меня скрипт, который проверяет наличие трансляции на Twitch и записывает видео, возьмем ее в качестве основы

```
client_id = "jzkbprff40iqj646a697cyrvl0zt2m6" # не изменять
def check_user():
    # 0: online, 
    # 1: offline, 
    # 2: not found, 
    # 3: error
    url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + username
    info = None
    status = 3
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, headers = {"Client-ID" : client_id}, timeout = 15)
        r.raise_for_status()
        info = r.json()
        if info['stream'] == None:
            status = 1
        else:
            status = 0
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        if e.response:
            if e.response.reason == 'Not Found' or e.response.reason == 'Unprocessable Entity':
                status = 2

    return status, info

def loopcheck():
    while True:
        status, info = self.check_user()
        if status == 0:
                #Отправляем сообщение в телеграм
            time.sleep(refresh)
```

В цикле каждые 15 секунд опрашиваем сервис о статусе трансляции, если она активна, то отправляем сообщение в телегу.

В качестве библиотеки можно использовать telethon.
А дальше зависит уже от вас, куда отправлять сообщение и как.

Также тут необходимо реализовать запоминание статуса, чтобы не отправлять сообщения постоянно, пока активна трансляция.

Comment: Я попробовал запустить код. Для начала решил просто вывести переменную status, а не отправлять сообщение в телеграм. В результате выбило ошибку. В чем проблема? Вот код: https://imgur.com/a/bWXgSrl

Comment: @bidlocoder228 сделай import time и переменной refresh дай значение >= 15

Comment: Я вывожу статус и инфо, но оно не изменяется. У обоих так и остаётся 3 и None. Можешь подсказать из-за чего?